# SQL Data Consolidation

Tags: sql

Assume I have a column called `name` and the values include:

```
Williams
Williamss
Wiliams
```

I would like to to consolidate these resulting names into one column  result of Williams. Is there an optimal means to do this?

Would this be the SQL expression to use?

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

Comment: Are this the only three values in the column and do you want a solution that will only work for those 3 values? If that’s the case then using a CASE statement is fine

Comment: There are about 20. Can I define the exceptions and do ELSE [keep existing value]